# getting inputs from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

i'd like to ask if i'm doing it right.

this is my code in my model:

```
function member_here()
{
$this->db->select('first_name');
$this->db->from('membership');
$this->db->where('username', 'username');

$q=$this->db->get();

if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
{
foreach($q->result() as $row) {
$data[]=$row;
    }
    return $data;
}
}
```

then, this is my code in my view:

```
    $CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('membership_model');
$result = $CI->membership_model->member_here();
var_dump($result);
```

I'm quite confused because, if i log in, my name doesn't appear in the page. anyway, if my code is wrong. how do i output SOME of the information from the database i am using?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    $data = array();
    foreach($q->result() as $row) {
        $data[]=$row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You need to initialize the $data variable before push into it..

Comment: but how about in my view form. its output is the word NULL. am i doing  it correct?

Comment: i made a mistake. i said controller instead of view. thats the only code i have. i dont have a controller for that. confused. sorry

Comment: i did what you said! i think it is working but not the output i expected. I did this:

 $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'))

and my result was the whole database in array.

i just need a string for an output.

Comment: well I dont know syntax of CI..I use YII..check if yor syntax of condition  is correct..